# How to find a non-zero number between two zeros in a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array `(11000x500)` with three different type of elements. 
1) Non-zero doubles
2) zero
3) Empty cell

I would like to find all occurances of a non-zero number between two zeros.

E.g. `A = {123 13232 132 0 56 0 12 0 0 [] [] []};`

I need the following output 
`out = logical([0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]);`

I used `cellfun` and  `isequal` like this

```
out = cellfun(@(c)(~isequal(c,0)), A);
```

and got the follwoing output

```
out = logical([1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]);
```

I need help to perform the next step where i can ignore the consecutive `1's` and only take the '1's'  between two `0's`

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conv` to find the elements with 0 neighbors (notice that the `~` has been removed from `isequal`):

```
out = cellfun(@(c)(isequal(c,0)), A);      % find 0 elements
out = double(out);                         % cast to double for conv
% elements that have more than one 0 neighbor
between0 = conv(out, [1 -1 1], 'same') > 1;

between0 =

   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

(Convolution kernel corrected to fix bug found by @TasosPapastylianou where 3 consecutive zeros would result in True.)

That's if you want a logical vector. If you want the indices, just add `find`:

```
between0 = find(conv(out, [1 -1 1], 'same') > 1);   

between0 =

   5   7
```

Comment: This works perfectly with a small correction. The variable `out` has to be converted to single or double! Thanks for the simple answer and the new function!!

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil You're right, MATLAB requires single or double. I tested this on Octave with allows logical arrays as well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Fixed, thanks for the heads-up! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick way to do it (and other manipulations binary data) using your `out`:

```
out = logical([1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]);
d = diff([out(1) out]); % find all switches between 1 to 0 or 0 to 1
len = 1:length(out); % make a list of all indices in 'out'
idx = [len(d~=0)-1 length(out)]; % the index of the end each group
counts = [idx(1) diff(idx)]; % the number of elements in the group
elements = out(idx); % the type of element (0 or 1)
singles = idx(counts==1 & elements==1)
```

and you will get:

```
singles =

   5   7
```

from here you can continue and create the output as you need it:

```
out = false(size(out)); % create an output vector
out(singles) = true % fill with '1' by singles
```

and you get:

```
out =

   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, this completely avoids your initial logical matrix though, I don't think you need it.

```
A = {123 13232 132 0 56 0 12 0 0 [] [] []};
N = length(A);

B = A;                                 % helper array
for I = 1 : N
   if isempty (B{I}), B{I} = nan; end; % convert empty cells to nans
end                                            
B = [nan, B{:}, nan];                  % pad, and collect into array

C = zeros (1, N);                      % preallocate your answer array
for I = 1 : N; 
  if ~any (isnan (B(I:I+2))) && isequal (logical (B(I:I+2)), logical ([0,1,0]))
    C(I) = 1; 
  end
end
C = logical(C)
```

```
C =
     0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```